# how to implement OnItemClickListener in this code?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to implement OnItemClickListener in this ListView ,But when i add code for this,my app will not work even there is no error. its closes automatically when I click on the Listview item. Please help me, I am a beginner in Android. I am adding my whole code here.
I am doing a bluetooth device connectivity code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Set;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;

    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;

    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private TextView mStatusTv;
        private Button mActivateBtn;
        private Button mPairedBtn;
        private Button mScanBtn;
        private Button ledBtn;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;

        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

        private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mStatusTv           = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
            mActivateBtn        = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enable);
            mPairedBtn          = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_view_paired);
            mScanBtn            = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
            ledBtn              = (Button) findViewById(R.id.led);
            ledBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Ledbuttons.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            mBluetoothAdapter   = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            mProgressDlg        = new ProgressDialog(this);

            mProgressDlg.setMessage("Scanning...");
            mProgressDlg.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDlg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
            });

            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                showUnsupported();
            } else {
                mPairedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {              
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                        if (pairedDevices == null || pairedDevices.size() == 0) { 
                            showToast("No Paired Devices Found");
                        } else {
                            ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> list = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

                            list.addAll(pairedDevices);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);

                            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", list);

                            startActivity(intent);                      
                        }
                    }
                });

                mScanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                    }
                });

                mActivateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

                            showDisabled();
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                });

                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    showEnabled();
                } else {
                    showDisabled();
                }
            }

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
            }

            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

            super.onDestroy();
        }

        private void showEnabled() {
            mStatusTv.setText("Bluetooth is On");
            mStatusTv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            mActivateBtn.setText("Disable");        
            mActivateBtn.setEnabled(true);

            mPairedBtn.setEnabled(true);
            mScanBtn.setEnabled(true);
            ledBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        private void showDisabled() {
            mStatusTv.setText("Bluetooth is Off");
            mStatusTv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            mActivateBtn.setText("Enable");
            mActivateBtn.setEnabled(true);

            mPairedBtn.setEnabled(false);
            mScanBtn.setEnabled(false);
            ledBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }

        private void showUnsupported() {
            mStatusTv.setText("Bluetooth is unsupported by this device");

            mActivateBtn.setText("Enable");
            mActivateBtn.setEnabled(false);

            mPairedBtn.setEnabled(false);
            mScanBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }

        private void showToast(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                    final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                    if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
                        showToast("Enabled");

                        showEnabled();
                     }
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                    mDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

                    mProgressDlg.show();
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                    mProgressDlg.dismiss();

                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);

                    newIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("device.list", mDeviceList);

                    startActivity(newIntent);
                } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    mDeviceList.add(device);

                    showToast("Found device " + device.getName());
                }
            }
        };
```

**DeviceListActivity.java**

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;

    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {
        private ListView mListView;
        private DeviceListAdapter mAdapter;
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDeviceList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mDeviceList     = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("device.list");

            mListView       = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_paired);

            mAdapter        = new DeviceListAdapter(this);

            mAdapter.setData(mDeviceList);
            mAdapter.setListener(new DeviceListAdapter.OnPairButtonClickListener() {            
                @Override
                public void onPairButtonClick(int position) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = mDeviceList.get(position);

                    if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        unpairDevice(device);
                    } else {
                        showToast("Pairing...");

                        pairDevice(device);
                    }
                }
            });

            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            registerReceiver(mPairReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED)); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            unregisterReceiver(mPairReceiver);

            super.onDestroy();
        }


        private void showToast(String message) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            try {
                Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
                method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            try {
                Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
                method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private final BroadcastReceiver mPairReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {             
                     final int state        = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);
                     final int prevState    = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

                     if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
                         showToast("Paired");
                     } else if (state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE && prevState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED){
                         showToast("Unpaired");
                     }

                     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };

    }
```

**DeviceListAdapter.java**

```
    import java.util.List;

    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.content.Context;

    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class DeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;   
        private List<BluetoothDevice> mData;
        private OnPairButtonClickListener mListener;

        public DeviceListAdapter(Context context) { 
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);        
        }

        public void setData(List<BluetoothDevice> data) {
            mData = data;
        }

        public void setListener(OnPairButtonClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return (mData == null) ? 0 : mData.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {          
                convertView         =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_device, null);

                holder              = new ViewHolder();

                holder.nameTv       = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                holder.addressTv    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
                holder.pairBtn      = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_pair);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device  = mData.get(position);

            holder.nameTv.setText(device.getName());
            holder.addressTv.setText(device.getAddress());
            holder.pairBtn.setText((device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) ? "Unpair" : "Pair");
            holder.pairBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onPairButtonClick(position);
                    }
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView nameTv;
            TextView addressTv;
            TextView pairBtn;
        }

        public interface OnPairButtonClickListener {
            public abstract void onPairButtonClick(int position);
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#060606"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text_bluetooth_off"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_enable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="#585858"
            android:text="@string/text_enable" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_view_paired"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="#585858"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/text_view_paired"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_scan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="#585858"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/text_scan_devices"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/led"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="#585858"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="LEDS"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="List Of Devices"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_paired"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**list_item_device.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Pair"
            android:textColor="#ff4444" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:text="Galaxy Nexus"
            android:textColor="#99cc00"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_pair"
            android:text="000000000"
            android:textColor="#ffbd21" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My Problems that not solved are

1. The app is not working when I add an onItemclicklistener to the list view.
2. bluetooth search result is filling with the same device name.
3. I cannot access the buttons after viewing pairing devices and
   scanned devices(it seems like that the same layout is popping to screen).

   Anyone please help me to solve these issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also show your onItemClick code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do like this -

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " ITEM CLICKED POSITION = "+String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add OnItemClickListener like this

```
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) { {

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
          }
        });`
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this code it contain how you set the list view listener with detect the clicked row and getting sub view in that row

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               View row=  adapter.getView(position, view, parent);
                 CheckBox box=(CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                 box.performClick();


            }

        });
```

adapter is your list view adapter
hope it help